Optimizing APS Forge Viewer for Large Models on Low-Memory Devices
We are considering providing functionality on devices with relatively low memory, such as the iPad, using a large model.
As an example, we are using the 9th generation device.
https://support.apple.com/en-asia/111898
If we try to render the model on the latest version of APS Forge Viewer (GuiViewer3D) using the iPad without any optimization, the iPad's screen goes completely white and the operation does not work.
We have also confirmed that the same issue occurs when opening the model on an iPad using Autodesk ACC or BIM360, which leads us to believe that the large size of the models we are handling is causing high memory usage within the Forge Viewer.
Therefore, we would like to know about any features or settings available in the APS Forge Viewer to operate the viewer in a memory-efficient manner to alleviate this situation.
One possibility we are considering is the selective-loading feature, but we are not sure if it is effective in reducing memory usage (either GPU or CPU).
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/advanced_options/selective-loading/
Another potential solution we are considering is using the Autodesk.MemoryLimited extension.
(example: Opening larger models on mobile devices using APS viewer (Autodesk.MemoryLimited))
However, we have not been able to find documentation detailing its features and caveats, so we are unsure whether it will affect the functionality we are considering.
We have not yet found other features or settings, so it would be helpful if you could broadly inform us of any features that might help reduce memory usage.
If this is particularly challenging, we are considering adjusting the model or view in Revit files, but we would like to consider this as a last resort.

You can explore selective loading, there are new improvements in SVF2. Autodesk.MemoryLimited is being deprecated, please do not use it.
The recommended solution is to use SVF2 for a lower memory footprint, break down the file into multiple files like architectural, mep, electrical, etc., and then do aggregated loading based on the need.
EDIT:
Please refer to these two blogs, you can use OPFS Caching as well.
Improving Viewer Performance Part 1
Improving Viewer Performance Part 2

Thank you for your prompt response.
Could you please provide more details regarding selective loading?

"you have to fetch metadata separately and object selection doesn't work."

Does this mean the following?

It takes more time and effort because we need to fetch metadata separately to create a query for selective loading.
The object selection feature is currently not working correctly due to some issues.


In selective loading, when you pass dbids, only those objects are displayed, but you cannot select those objects and see the metadata, if displaying is the only purpose, then selective loading is fine.

Thank you for your response.
I have reviewed the materials you provided and will do my best.
I apologize for asking again, but I have one more additional question. One of our requirements is offline viewing. I found in the documentation that the current svf2 does not support offline viewing.
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/basics/preperation/
If there are any future plans to make svf2 available for offline viewing, could you please let me know?

@y.sayama it was never officially supported in the first place. So anything here would be a custom extension.

@y.sayama About selective loading, earlier there were limitations in SVF. Now we have new improvements in SVF2, I have added the link to the answer. You can use selective loading as one of the options.
